# fullpage color but white in text width and text height

Tags: pagecolor

I need full page as some color but the text height and width should be in white and the text in black color, I got the full page color by using the below tag:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{cyan!10}

This is for test
\end{document}
```

Entire page came as in color, but how to get the text height and width in white color, please suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `scrlayer` you can create a page layer which is in the background and only contains a white box as big as the text area:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,everypage,everyside,textarea,contents={\color{white}\vrule width\hsize height\vsize},mode=picture]{textbackground}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{textbackground}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{cyan!10}

This is for text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
\AtPageLowerLeft{{\color{cyan!10}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
\AtTextLowerLeft{{\color{white}\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}}}
}
\begin{document}
This is for test
\end{document}
```